# expects() of a spec visible outside to other specs when running 'rspec spec'

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have two specs which when individually run, execute fine but when i execute them using 'rspec spec' the latter fails.

First:

```
    describe "DB Archival" do
      it "should archive the nodes which are deleted" do
        node_data_archival = mock()
        NodeDataArchival.expects(:new).with('node1').returns(node_data_archival)
        node_data_archival.expects(:export_to_csv).with([1,2])
        db_archival.archive_deleted_nodes
      end
    end
```

Second:

```
describe "Export to CSV" do
  it "should export data to a csv file" do
    class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    end

    School.expects(:column_names).returns(["id", "name"])
    node_data_archival = NodeDataArchival.new("school")
    node_data_archival.export_to_csv(rows, filename)
   end
end
```

The second throws up with:

```
$ rspec spec
.......F......

Failures:

  1) Export to CSV should export data to a csv file
     Failure/Error: node_data_archival1 = NodeDataArchival.new("school")
     Mocha::ExpectationError:
       unexpected invocation: NodeDataArchival.new('school')
       unsatisfied expectations:
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: School(Table doesn't exist).column_names(any_parameters)
       satisfied expectations:
       - expected exactly once, invoked once: NodeDataArchival.new('node1')
       - expected exactly once, invoked once: #<RSpec::Mocks::Mock:0x7ff4693d3028>.export_to_csv([1, 2])
     # ./spec/entity_traversal/node_data_archival_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My question is -
1) why is it trying to find an expectation instead of creating an actual instance of NodeDataArchival in second spec? 
2) why second spec is able to find the expects() declared by first spec?

PS: The issue is happening only when i am running all specs together using 'rspec spec' and both specs are running fine individually.

EDIT: 
Versions used:
ruby-1.9.3-p125, 
rspec (2.13.0) 
and mocha (0.14.0)

EDIT: Using rspec-rails-mocha (0.3.2) instead of mocha (0.14.0) solved the issue.

Comment: The expectations shouldn't be "leaking", but can you share your full specs? Also, are these the only two specs in your spec/ directory (i.e. are these the only two specs run when you execute `rspec spec`)?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin yeah, basically just running these two specs is giving the error. I have mentioned both here [link]http://pastebin.com/jZ50Fnd6 . Also, i resolved it by using should_receive in the first spec, looks like an issue with expects()

Comment: Did you concatenate the two files and paste as one? I ask because there was only one `require 'spec_helper'` in there.

Comment: Can you explain why there are so many `.` output by rspec? I thought there was supposed to be one for each `it` invocation, of which you only have two across the two files.

Comment: yeah i concatenated and pasted from two spec files. But even in single spec(like i pasted), both are in separate describes. So, expects() of the above shouldn't be visible to the other one?

Comment: Does the single spec (with both describes) fail in the same way as running the two separate specs?

Comment: Yeah, in the same manner. Various dots were because of many its i ran earlier. This is the output for the single spec file(only these 2 specs) that i ran now http://pastebin.com/2dm6VQiT

Comment: I just noticed that you're using Mocha mocks. Have you tried rspec mocks?  I don't know if it's related, but I found https://github.com/freerange/mocha/issues/138

Comment: wow, that worked. So, rspec-mock are more stable than mocha? Alos, Thanks so much for help, @PeterAlfvin

Comment: Would you please share what version of Ruby, rspec and mocha you are using?

Comment: Sure, ruby-1.9.3-p125, rspec (2.13.0) and mocha (0.14.0) showed the issue. Using rspec-rails-mocha (0.3.2) worked. [Also edited the question to add versions].

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment thread, this appears to be a rather serious incompatibility between the ruby, rspec and mocha versions you cited. No such issue has been submitted to mocha's github site, let alone included in their "Known Issues" documentation.

Although the mocha gem seems to have been implicitly deprecated for rspec use by the rspec-rails-mocha gem you subsequently tried, you might want to submit an issue against mocha. If you want to be a particularly good citizen, you could try out ruby 2.0 and rspec 2.14 before doing so to see what impact they have.